# Logstash Twitter plugin `Error::Forbidden`

Tags: twitter, logstash

I am running `logstash 7.16.2` on an `Amazon Linux 2 AMI` with the following command:

`bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/twitter.conf`

Here is the content of `twitter.conf`:

```
input {
  twitter {
    id => "twitter_plugin_1"
    consumer_key => "MY_CONSUMER_KEY"
    consumer_secret => "MY_CONSUMER_SECRET"
    oauth_token => "MY_OAUTH_TOKEN"
    oauth_token_secret => "MY_OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET"
    use_samples => true
  }
}

output {
    stdout {
      codec => json
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

> `` [WARN ] 2022-01-18 01:11:58.701 [[main]<twitter] twitter - Twitter client error {:message=>"", :exception=>Twitter::Error::Forbidden, :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/streaming/response.rb:24:in `on_headers_complete'", "org/ruby_http_parser/RubyHttpParser.java:370:in `<<'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/streaming/response.rb:19:in `<<'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/streaming/connection.rb:20:in `stream'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/streaming/client.rb:119:in `request'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/twitter-6.2.0/lib/twitter/streaming/client.rb:59:in `sample'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-twitter-4.0.3/lib/logstash/inputs/twitter.rb:146:in `do_run'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-twitter-4.0.3/lib/logstash/inputs/twitter.rb:131:in `run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:409:in `inputworker'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:400:in `block in start_input'"], :options=>nil} ``

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: It looks like the plugin is trying to call an API endpoint that it does not have access to. Are you using the Twitter API v2, or v1.1? I do not believe that the logstash Twitter plugin supports v2.

Comment: I am using Twitter API v2. Do you know if support for v2 is coming any time soon?@AndyPiper

Comment: I’m not the author of logstash or the Ruby gem it uses (and they are not created by Twitter), you would need to ask those projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem was that I have credentials for Twitter API V2 and the Logstash Twitter Plugin was trying to reach Twitter API V1 endpoints. The problem will remain until a plugin is developed for Twitter API V2.

Comment: According to an issue that I shared on twitter community, a new plugin for v2 should be developped.

Answer (score 1):

According to an issue that I shared on twitter community, a new plugin for v2 should be developed.

For more details, refer to this topic: https://twittercommunity.com/t/connect-logstash-to-twitter-app-v2/172503